# How to Show only the data-filter of the List-View in JQuery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I want to show only the Data-Filter box (where the user filter the list).

this is my code so far, i need to hide the list elements and show them only when the user starts typing and if possible after the user types 1 character.

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Destination">
    <li> Zara
    <li> H&M
    <li> Baskin Robins
    <li> Aldo
    <li> BeBe
    <li> Cilantro
    <li> Beanos
    <li> Costa - L1
    <li> Costa - L2
    <li> Costa - L3
</ul>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `data-filter-reveal="true"` add it to `ul`. read this http://api.jquerymobile.com/filterable/#option-filterReveal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this you should use Autocomplete box of jquerymobile. Find the link below.

> http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/widgets/autocomplete/